Snowflake - Set Start Day for a week to Monday, then get week start and week end dates for a date field
In Snowflake, I was looking to

set the 'Start Day' for a week to Monday, so that each week spans Monday to Sunday
then get the 'start date' (which should be a Monday) and 'end date' (which should be a sunday) for a date field


Managed to solve this issue by running:
--SET start of a week to Monday
ALTER SESSION SET WEEK_START=1;


SELECT ORIGINAL_DATE_FIELD,
       DATEADD('DAY', -6, LAST_DAY(ORIGINAL_DATE_FIELD, 'WEEK')) AS MONDAY_START_DATE, --MONDAY'S START DATE FOR THE WEEK
       LAST_DAY(ORIGINAL_DATE_FIELD, 'WEEK') AS SUNDAY_END_DATE
FROM TABLE_NAME;


--You can test using Sunday and Monday dates below (ie our boundary values)
--Sunday date
SELECT TO_DATE('2024-08-11'),
       DATEADD('DAY', -6, LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('2024-08-11'), 'WEEK')) AS MONDAY_START_DATE, --MONDAY'S START DATE FOR THE WEEK
       LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('2024-08-11'), 'WEEK') AS SUNDAY_END_DATE;

--Monday date
SELECT TO_DATE('2024-08-12'),
       DATEADD('DAY', -6, LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('2024-08-12'), 'WEEK')) AS MONDAY_START_DATE, --MONDAY'S START DATE FOR THE WEEK
       LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('2024-08-12'), 'WEEK') AS SUNDAY_END_DATE;


Reference:

alternative for alter session set week_start in snowflake

